# Python Script works when run manually, but not on startup: "String Index Out of Range"

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out why this script will run perfectly when I run it thorugh command line, but when I try to run it on startup using *crontab* it gives me an error: `IndexError: string index out of range`.

**Background**:

My script tracks the WIFI signal strength as a two digit number, and based on the signal strength it performs Lock and Unlock functions on my car, depending on how close I am with my phone.

The reason I want to run the script on startup, my Pi is configured to connect to my phones Wifi hotspot. When I run the python script manually through SSH, the SSH will disconnect and the script will stop if I go out of range. The pi will automatically reconnect to my phones hotspot when I am in range, but I have to manually restart the script each time.

The line that gives me an error (only when running on startup) is :

```
wifi = int(msg[13] + msg[14])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Whats going on here? Why does this only happen when I try to run as a background script on startup. Otherwise it outputs just the two digit signal strength and works as intended.

Here is the full code. The concept is when I get close to my car with my phone, it automatically unlocks. When the signal strength weakens as I get further away, the car automatically locks.

I added a few notes in the code to explain what is going on, I had to do some clever stuff just to get the Wifi signal as a number. (why is such a seemingly simple thing like that such a hard thing to do?)

```
from subprocess import *
import RPi.GPIO as io
import time

io.setmode(io.BCM)
io.setwarnings(False)

UNLK = 16
LOCK = 12

io.setup(UNLK, io.OUT)
io.setup(LOCK, io.OUT)
io.output(UNLK, 1)
io.output(LOCK, 1)

##I took this block from a script I found online when Googling different ways to get the Wifi signal in

##Python, this is the best one I could find that worked. I have really no idea what grep, Popen and some 

##of these commands are, but it works when I add the indexing part below.

def getQuality():
    shell_cmd = 'iwconfig {} | grep Link'.format('wlan0')
    proc = Popen(shell_cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    output, err = proc.communicate()
    msg = output.decode('utf-8').strip()

##I added this block after eventually figuring out how to use the brackets [] to "index" the output of 

##the previous block and only get the two digits (position 13 and 14 of the output) (the output is 

##always Link Quality = ??/70 where ?? are the 13th and 14th position of the line.)

    wifi = int(msg[13] + msg[14]) ##this is the line that both gives me the magic number that I need to make this script work, but also the only line that trying to run on startup doesn't like

    return wifi

### Everything below works fine #####
### lockstat.txt is a txt file with either 1 or 0 to track the Locked status of my car ## 

def getLocked():
    with open("lockstat.txt", "r") as LOCKED:
        if '1' in LOCKED:
            return True

while True:

    if getLocked():
        if getQuality() >= 35:
            print("Unlocked")
            io.output(16, 0)
            time.sleep(.1)
            io.output(16, 1)
            with open("lockstat.txt", "w") as LOCKED:
                LOCKED.write('0')
    else:
        if getQuality() < 35:
            print("Locked")
            io.output(12, 0)
            time.sleep(.1)
            io.output(12, 1)
            with open("lockstat.txt", "w") as LOCKED:
                LOCKED.write('1')
    print(getQuality())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: check the length of the string `msg`, it should be greater than >=15 to get `msg[14]`.

Comment: Hmm, i ran into the same issue while developing an app for `TESLA`. i can confirm for you that you need to make a sleep around 5 second while start up done to let the device be connected to `WIFI` network ! that's all

Comment: Use `try: wifi = int(msg[13] + msg[14])  return wifi` `except: print("Device not yet connected to wifi") return(0)`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Try did get rid of the error message. However, it seems even after the Wifi is connected the try: expression is still failing every time and the script appears to be doing nothing.

Comment: Then print the exception and see where the error is. Use `except Exception as e: print(str(e))`. According to @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη you need to let it sleep and connect to Wifi.  Maybe try sleeping and looping till `len(msg)>=14`.